# Instantly hide or show based on PHP variable text in HTML with jQuery

Tags: php, html, jquery

I'm working on something like this so that when the cart count is 0, the page will be hidden without needing to refresh, and if it's higher than 0, the page will be shown without refresh.

My HTML, `0` is a variable.

```
<span class="wd-cart-number">0</span>
```

jQuery

```
       $( document ).ready( function($) {
            if( 0 == $('.wd-cart-number').text() ) {
                $( '.wd-cart-number' ).hide();
            } else {
                $( '.wd-cart-number' ).show();
            }
        });
```

UPDATE, How do I use the code.

This is my jQuery script

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'hide_cart_count' );
    function hide_cart_count() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready( function($) {
            if( 0 == $( '.wd-cart-number' ).text() ) {
                $( '.wd-cart-number' ).hide();
            } else {
                $( '.wd-cart-number' ).show();
            }
        });

</script>
<?php
}
```

This is my PHP script, actually I'm showing 0 and above here but it doesn't work until the page is refreshed. So I'm trying to try something different with jQuery.

```
    function woodmart_cart_count() {
    
        $count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
        if (  $count >= 0 ) :
        ?>
  <span class="wd-cart-number<?php echo woodmart_get_old_classes( ' woodmart-cart-number' ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $count ); ?></span>
        <?php
        endif;
   }
```

PHP code output`<span class="wd-cart-number">0</span>` or above `0`.

Comment: Do you have a specific problem? In isolation, the code should work fine. If it's not working for you check what the `text()` call is returning.

Comment: Frankly, I'm not good at jQuery. I don't know if I should make it .html or .text. It doesn't work at all right now.

Comment: have you looked in the console for errors, when I run this code in codepen, it works.

Comment: If you're struggling with implementing the code, can you please show all your HTML/JS so we can see that you've added the necessary references in to the right locations.

Comment: Now I added an edit and it still doesn't work! I'm also using a site-wide jQuery library, so I guess there's no need to hook into jQuery.

Comment: Since this is wordpress, have your tried using `jQuery( document ).ready` instead of `$( document ).ready`?

Comment: @ersezar
 If you are using Wodpress you can use wp heartbeat to check the value and based on that you can run your condition as, heartbeat is running every-time after some time so it works well with your condition.

Comment: Adding 999 at the end of the hook `add_action( 'wp_footer', 'hide_cart_count', 999 );` fixed the problem, thank you very much for your help!